# Count 2 tables + string

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count two columns on two different tables, with the same name. One column have rows, `example: AB0000` and the second column (from the second table) have rows: `B0000`. I need to put **`A`** at the second columns to all the rows. What did I do wrong here?

```
SELECT [Column_A] 
from
 Table_A  
where
(
Select Count([Column_A]) from Table_A a
where [TIME_DATE_From_Column_A] BETWEEN '2014-06-30 00:00:00' and '2014-07-07 00:00:00'
) 
(
SELECT  'A'+[Column_B] 
from Table_B  b
)
```

Comment: Please a example data and expected output in a table like form.

Comment: the result needs to be like:
  (No Column name)
1 120           
2 200

I need to check values from both columns if the ID's are the same or not, need's to be like: AB001(1row from first column, on the first table) and on the second column from the second table need's to be same like AB001 , but it's B001 and to can be count if they are the same, those needs to be same string..

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select column_a, count(*) as a,
       (select count(*)
        from table_b b
        where b.column_a = 'A' + column_b
       ) b
from Table_A  a
where [TIME_DATE_From_Column_A] between '2014-06-30 00:00:00' and '2014-07-07 00:00:00'
group by column_a;
```

Comment: and what i can do to see if the ID's are the same or not!?

Comment: and what i can do to see if the ID's are the same or not!? cuz the result its: ID: id_number a: 1 b: 0 .  to all the rows.. and i need to see if they are the same or not :/

Comment: @boggdan . . . If you have another question, you shouldn't ask it in comments.  You should post a well-formatted question with sample data, desired results, table layouts (if needed) and query(s) that you have tried.